# Не работает annotations в Symfony5

Tags: php, symfony, аннотации, symfony5

Подключил annotations в symfony 5 проект.

При создании аннотации на url '/', все работает корректно, но если пытаюсь создать любой другой url, например '/test' то получаю ошибку 404. При дебаге роутера, видно что контроллер и метод для пути '/test' находятся правильно, но в браузере путь не работает. Уже не знаю куда смотреть и что искать, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает в чем тут дело?

Код контроллера:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ParserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        print 'index';
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     */
    public function test()
    {
        print 'test';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Скриншот дэбага:

[image: Скриншот дэбага]

Comment: а если `/index.php/test` ?

Comment: А зачем exit? В примерах Симфонии разве есть его использование в методах контроллера? По сути, вы им обрываете выполнение кода!

Comment: @DanielProtopopov строка всё равно должна выполнится, автор таким образом хочет проверить работает ли данный роут

Comment: Попробуйте почистить кэш

Comment: Вместо `print 'test'; exit;` сделайте все же `return new Response('OK', 200);`

Comment: Роут работает только с url-ом вида '/public/index.php/test'. Думаю не так прописано перенаправление в /public директорию, в .htaccess файле. Пойду шаманить. Спасибо @Alpha

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь! Проблема была в неправильном перенаправлении в папку /public проекта. Я его переписал и аннотации заработали корректно.

Файл /.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Файл /public/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```